# In development, outputting troubleshooting code only works well for standard page loads, ajax presents issues

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Summary: I have a solution I've built for monitoring variables and code processing in my environment. It works well for static pages, and the code below is a usable solution for that. However, if the page includes ajax calls which updates common variables after the page runs, this monitoring method isn't useful. To make it do so, I want to figure out a way to piggyback off an ajax call that will story information that's run in place, but I can't figure out how to work it into this code.

I have the following error checking file for php that I use in my development environment, the following using a magic function, register_tick_function, to store code as its run and show the variables for each step. Including it on a page allows the tick process to run...

```
<?php

register_tick_function(function(){
  if (isset($GLOBALS["developer_debug"]) && $GLOBALS["developer_debug"] == 'active'){
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $line = $backtrace[0]['line'] - 1;
    $file = $backtrace[0]['file'];

    if ($file == __FILE__) return;

    static $fp, $cur, $buf;
    if (!isset($fp[$file])) {
        $fp[$file] = fopen($file, 'r');
        $cur[$file] = 0;
    }

    if (isset($buf[$file][$line])) {
        $code = $buf[$file][$line];
    } else {
        do {
            $code = fgets($fp[$file]);
            $buf[$file][$cur[$file]] = $code;
        } while (++$cur[$file] <= $line);
    }

    $line++;
    if (defined('ERR_LOG')){ $error_log = ERR_LOG; } else {
      $error_log = "../logs/error_log";
    }
    error_log("\n==========================================================\n", 3, $error_log);
    error_log("\n $file : $line :: $code \n", 3, $error_log);
    error_log("\n Variables: \n" . print_r(get_defined_vars(), true) . "\n", 3, $error_log);
    $GLOBALS["_TROUBLESHOOTING"][] = "<code>\n $file : $line ::: ". htmlentities($code, ENT_QUOTES) . " \n</code>";
  }
}, ["_SERVER" => $_SERVER, "_COOKIE"=>$_COOKIE, "_REQUEST"=>$_REQUEST, "_SESSION"=>$_SESSION, "_GLOBALS"=>$GLOBALS]);
// To use...
// declare(ticks=1);
// include_once('debug.php');
```

and in my direct page loads (such as index.php) I can include this js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dev_top_button = document.createElement("Button");
  dev_top_button.innerHTML = "Top Dev Data";
  dev_top_button.style = "top:0;right:75%;position:absolute;z-index: 9999"
  document.body.appendChild(dev_top_button);

  var dev_bottom_button = document.createElement("Button");
  dev_bottom_button.innerHTML = "Bottom Dev Data";
  dev_bottom_button.style = "top:0;right:50%;position:absolute;z-index: 9999"
  document.body.appendChild(dev_bottom_button);

  $(dev_top_button).click(function(){
    $("#debug_top").toggle();
  });

  $(dev_bottom_button).click(function(){
    $("#debug_bottom").toggle();
  });
});
```

and this on the page itself:

```
        echo "<div class='debug_outer' id='debug_top'><h3>Developer Information</h3><div class='debug_inner'><pre>";

        if (isset($GLOBALS['_TROUBLESHOOTING']) && is_array($GLOBALS['_TROUBLESHOOTING']) && ! empty($GLOBALS['_TROUBLESHOOTING'])) {

            $troubleshooting_return_array = $GLOBALS['_TROUBLESHOOTING'];

        } else {

            $troubleshooting_return_array = ['Empty'];
        }

        echo print_r(["_COOKIE" => $_COOKIE, "_REQUEST" => $_REQUEST, "_SESSION" => $_SESSION, "_TROUBLESHOOTING" => $troubleshooting_return_array, "_SERVER" => $_SERVER, "_GLOBALS" => $GLOBALS], true);
        echo '</pre></div></div>';
```

(And a similar output at the end of the page)

So, for most pages, this method to quickly check out page variables works great. And results in a nice javascript button to where I can quickly check what my start and end variables are on a page, along with a _TROUBLESHOOTING array I can easily dump whatever values I want to for quick looking over at page start and end.

[image: Nice buttons and display to show page data]

So this system has been working pretty well for me for quite awhile now. The problem, however, comes with ajax calls. I've tried several different ways, but ajax calls generally want and expect data in a certain format. I'm -wanting- to make a third div for displaying data, along with a button for it, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to piggyback any output data along with an ajax call, and it *has* to be called when the ajax is called in order to get how all the variables change and to track anything I'm troubleshooting. Sure, I can put an output to the error logs each time, but that's way slower on workflow and requires grepping through all the output since the last time the logs were cleared rather than simply seeing what my data is as I'm manipulating it.

Does anyone have a good idea to piggyback off of ajax calls to take use of these existing kinds of calls? Because messing with the returned values of the ajax calls will always result in bad data for the ajax call itself.

Comment: Hello! Please supply a [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: @MilkyWay90 I appreciate the advice, but there's not really a good way to do that. This is a rather unique scenario about code that has to be run in-place in a certain way, and trying to integrate that in with ajax calls. I can't think of ways to reduce it without turning it into something else.

Comment: I see. I get it now

Comment: For example, the first block of code, once run, since it uses the tick function, will be firing off each line of code that's touched. It literally cannot be moved from its location, and demonstrates where later variables come from. The second block the js to populate it, which runs at ready time, which happens before any ajax call. The third is how the data actually gets on the page. It's pretty much all functional code to get to that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was fairly straightforward after I thought about it for a while:

For ajax requests, send the data to a sub-array in session; a sub-array that's normally ignored by by the normal two print outs. Then, have a third button that's an ajax request that specifically fetches the value of that sub-array. The sub-array can be specifically filled with a sub-sub array for each ajax call that has been done, and then when fetched by the third button, it creates a div to share it and then empty the sub-array (otherwise it will bloat way too quickly), allow seeing all ajax calls since the last time the button was clicked (and appending them to the existing list, if still on the same page.)